# How knockout js adding html dynamically clicking on button

Tags: knockout.js

i am fairly new in kncokout js. i noticed one code which is adding html dynamically into page when button clicked. here is the code. i am looking for help from some one who could help me to understand below code. here is a full code.

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.add = function () {
        self.items.push({});
    };

    self.doAlert = function() {
        alert('Hello World');
    } 
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

<button data-bind="click: add">Add Template</button>
<!-- ko template: { name: 'myTemplate', foreach: items } -->
<!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.doAlert">Do Alert</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

the area which is not clear is when clicking button then a empty element is getting added to items array and a new html is getting added to page. how it is getting possible.

the below syntax is also not clear.

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'myTemplate', foreach: items } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout uses bindings to bind your model (javascript) to your view (html). The `data-bind` attribute you see in the html, is used to tell which parts of your view should be binded to functions or fields of your model.

Knockout also uses observable properties and collections in your model side.

So when you click the `Add Template` button, knockout invokes the `add` method in your model, because the button is using a [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

The `add` function then pushes a new object to the `items` collection. As the collection is observable, knockout knows immediately that the model changed, and follows any dependency in the dependency graph that it had built when `applyBinginds` was invoked, and updates dependants when appropriate.

The `<!-- ko template: .... -->` is [another kind of binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), which in your case is binded to the `items` collection. So immediately after the observable collection changed, knockout runned the binded template to the new object in the collection, producing the resulting new `div` in your page.

If you're fairly new to knockout, I suggest you take the time to do the [tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) and peek the [live examples](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/), as they are a fantastic source of knowledge.